# The method is no applicable to the arguments in Java

Tags: java, object, methods

I am fairly new to objects and classes in Java, so sorry for the newbie question. In the main method's print statement I get the error:

> The method getId(int) in the type Account is not applicable for the arguments ()

I am not quite sure what exactly is happening here, but I am just trying to print user2's id. Thank you in advance.

I also do apologize for trying to get all the code into a single block, but I had some issues, clearly.

```java
package problems;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class AccountTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //User 1 with no input values
        Account user1 = new Account();
        //User 2 with the specified id and balance values
        Account user2 = new Account(1122, 20000);
        
        //Test to see if the getters and setters work
        System.out.println("The id is + " + user2.getId());
    }
    

}

//Create the class

class Account {
    private int id;
    private double balance;
    private static double annualInterestRate;
    private LocalDate dateCreated;
    
    //Object for when no values are passed
    Account() {
        id = 0;
        balance = 0;
        annualInterestRate = 4.5;
        System.out.println("There are no parameters set for the object");
    }
    //Object for when values are passed
    Account(int id, int balance) {
        this.id = id;
        this.balance = balance;
        annualInterestRate = 4.5;
        dateCreated = LocalDate.now();
        
    }
    
    //Getters
    public int getId(int id) {
        return  this.id;
    }
    public  double getBalance(double balance) {
        return this.balance;
    }
    public double getMonthlyInterest(double annualInterestRate) {
        return (annualInterestRate / 100 /12 * balance);
    }
    
    //Setters
    public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }
    
    
    //Deposit and withdraw methods
    public double withdraw(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance - 2500;
        return this.balance;
    }
    public double deposit(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance + 3000;
        return this.balance;
    }
    
    //Get the date for when the account was made
    public long getDate(long dateCreated) {
        return dateCreated;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The error means that your method declaration like `getId(int id)` takes in one argument, but you are calling the method with no arguments. Getters typically don't have arguments, so `public int getId(int id) {` should be `public int getId() {`

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, when you do a getter, you get a value, so there is no point in giving it an argument when all it does is return the value of the private variable.

Example:

```
private String myVar;

public String getMyVar()
{
  return this.myVar;
}

public void setMyVar(String theValueIWantMyVar)
{
  this.myVar = theValueIWantMyVar;
}
```

I recommend you read a little to see how object oriented programming works

https://dev.to/codegym_cc/18-best-java-books-for-beginners-in-2019-fme

Comment: You can close the question accepting my answer, i hope help you @JaydenLeuciuc